# VS 2010 Professional Retail box license question

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, licensing

I'm trying to persuade my boss to purchase copies of Visual Studio 2010 Pro (Retail) for some of us team members to develop with so we can move to developing with .net 4.0 and mvc 3 when the time comes, but I'm getting some resistance. The confusion is on the licensing terms.

It has always been my understanding that 1 retail purchase is good for 1 developer to develop code on. That code may then be used to create products that could be resold or what have you. I've been reviewing the licensing terms and the language is pretty confusing. I found a white paper on it here:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2b1504e6-0bf1-46da-be0e-85cc792c6b9d&displaylang=en

The white paper also provides a link to get the license for retail copies of various microsoft products. That url is:

http://www.microsoft.com/About/Legal/EN/US/IntellectualProperty/UseTerms/Default.aspx

(I selected Visual Studio, 2010 Pro Edition, English).

On page 2 of the pdf, the following text is found (2.a)

a. General. One user may install and use copies of the software to design, develop, test and demonstrate your programs. You may not use the software on a server in a production environment.

I took this to mean that you can't actually install the development software on your production machine, but you can deploy whatever you have developed else where to production so long as that machine has the necessary licenses for Windows Server, Sql Server, Sharepoint, etc (pretty much whatever you're to use). Is this correct?

Also, users aren't required to have a license to access a web application hosted on a production server are they? I'm specifically asking about Microsoft licenses a user might need to access, say, an intranet site developed by a licensed programmer using Visual Studio 2010 Professional. The question seems absurd to me, but I need some kind of clarification if at all possible.

Comment: Consider getting Software Assurance or an MSDN subscription.

Comment: An MSDN subscription is probably the best way to go, if you can afford it. Not only will you get tons of useful tools and resources, but you won't have to worry about licensing issues like this that detract from developer productivity.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you should be asking a lawyer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio is just the development environment hence anything you develop with it can be distributed however you like. If you build .NET applications then the end users don't need any licence to run applications, so long as you're not including any third party component which has additional licensing requirements.

If you build WinForms/WPF applications then all that is needed to run them is the .NET Framework for the version you have used to build it.

If you build an ASP.NET application then nobody who access that application requires a licence to do so. The site served up by IIS which is covered by the server licence it is on. A caveat to that would be something like Sharepoint which does require CALs.

Depending upon how an instance of SQL Server is installed accessing SQL Server databases can require CALs (not for Express edition).

You will require one licensed copy of Visual Studio for each developer, but don't buy a boxed retail product, that's pretty much the most expensive way to buy it. Look into an MSDN subscription with Visual Studio, much more cost effective. Depending upon your reseller you can even buy it with an Open Value licence and spread the cost over three years, which gives you an MSDN subscription and most development tools for the same timeframe. Once the subscription is up then the licences become perpetual.

Answer (score 1):

I think 1 copy per developer is fine - you don't need a version of VS 2010 on the production machine as it doesn't require it for hosting

all it will need is the ASP.NET framework to run the application

Answer (score 1):

I think clause 2.a is designed to prevent you from buying one copy of Visual Studio and allowing multiple developers to use it via terminal services.  The clause is pretty vague, though, and seems counter-intuitive.

Also, depending on your needs, you may not need the professional version.  Visual Studio Express allows commercial application development, but there are limitations in what technologies it supports, as well as lack of plug-ins and some other things.  Check to see if your needs are covered by Visual Studio Express before you buy the Pro version.

Comment: Thanks for specifically commenting on the 2.a clause. I figured it was something like that.